# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'quill-editor'

Tags: angular-test

I am getting error `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'quill-editor'` in my app-component-spec.ts`for line`[ERROR ->]

The line code in the `QuestionListComponent.html` is

`<quill-editor class="description-row" [style]="editorStyle" [readOnly]="true" [modules]="editorConfig" [(ngModel)]="question.description"></quill-editor>`

`quill-editor` is part of `component`QuillEditorComponent`defined in`QuillModule`which I have imported in`app.module.ts`.

```
imports: [
    AceEditorModule,
    QuillModule,
```

Why am I still getting the error? If I add `QuillEditorComponent` explicitly again in my test then I get error

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
QuillEditorComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        QuillModule,
]
...
});
```

`Type QuillEditorComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: QuillModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving QuillEditorComponent to a higher module that imports QuillModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes QuillEditorComponent then import that NgModule in QuillModule and DynamicTestModule.`

If I remove the code `[(ngModel)]="question.description"` then the code compiles. I am unable to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to also add `FormsModule`. I only had `ReactiveFormsModule` in `imports`.